# Cannot re-create app due to error "This Firebase URL is not available"

Tags: hosting, firebase

I decided to try out Firebase hosting and wanted to start fresh so I deleted my one and only app, but when I tried to create a new app with the same name I was unable to due to the error:

"This Firebase URL is not available"

I can only guess this is because of caching of app names/URLs? Hopefully it will become available (unless someone else beats me to it) after some timeout? Any info from others who have experience with this issue or otherwise know the answer is appreciated!

Not sure whether this is the right place to ask although Firebase suggest coming to SO because they apparently monitor Firebase-related questions closely according to their website.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a great place to ask questions related to Firebase and we definitely monitor this channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you delete a Firebase URL, it is permanently unavailable. It cannot be recovered.

During confirmation, you should see a message like this, which explains in detail:

[image]

This stems from a number of abuse vectors that are possible by misappropriating a project id that the prior owner believes is deleted and could still have apps/releases in the wild attached to the defunct backend. Since compliance requires that we purge all data related to the project, including information about ownership, there's not even a way to restore one you personally deleted.

Comment: I can't recall seeing that but I do recall typing the namespace to confirm... I think. I should not build apps while tired ;)

Comment: In 2021, is this still true?

Comment: it is still an abuse vector to be able to relaunch someone else's deleted project, so yes, it's still not allowed.